# "from pyoptsparse import Optimization" not a valid reference in pyoptsparse_driver.py

Tags: python-3.x, openmdao

This is line 18 in pyoptsparse_driver.py

```
from pyoptsparse import Optimization
```

I don't think this is a valid reference to anything. Just trying to work through a simple optimization example from test_pyoptsparse_driver.py See LINE 1575
I tried changing the optimizer from NSGA2 to SLSQP

I don't know why you need this function

```
_, local_opt = set_pyoptsparse_opt('NSGA2')
```

Line 330 of set_pyoptsparse_opt calls

```
from pyoptsparse import OPT
```

Where is pyoptsparse coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Pyoptsparse is coming from the MDOLab at UMich and the repo can be found [here](https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse). To run that example you will need to clone and install the repo using the steps below. OpenMDAO is currently using v1.2 but if you want the latest, simply skip that step.

```
git clone https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse.git
cd pyoptsparse
git checkout tags/v1.2
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install .
```